# install Raspbian from .img on windows

Tags: sd-card, windows

I just download a .img file, and formatted my SD card.
Now, what should I do in order to install the distribution on the card for raspberry boot?

Comment: Formatting was a completely unnessessary step, you are just going to blow that partition away anyway, the IMG you dowloaded _is not just a file, it is aa disk image complete with partitions and formatting intact_. See the question linked as a duplicate for details.

Comment: Just want to add a little. Use [SD Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) to format SD cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [WinDiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/). Just select your file and drive and hit write.

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us which .img you downloaded or what you've already tried.

You can read here for how to use Win32DiskImager: http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_Card_using_Windows

Or you could try NOOBS instead, that's another way to do it and very very easy. Just unpack the zip to the sd card.  See [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

Comment: Seems to be a good alternative, but I wanted to use a special .img, thanks